# How to query ports are using by one process with knowing its name or pid on mac?

Tags: macos, shell

I want to query ports are using by one process,I have known the pid of the process using `ps aux | grep <name regex of process>`,but I don't know how to get the ports being used by it.On linux,we can use `netstat -anp | grep <pid>`,but the command doesn't work on mac,it throws such hint:

```
netstat: option requires an argument -- p
Usage:  netstat [-AaLlnW] [-f address_family | -p protocol]
netstat [-gilns] [-f address_family]
netstat -i | -I interface [-w wait] [-abdgRtS]
netstat -s [-s] [-f address_family | -p protocol] [-w wait]
netstat -i | -I interface -s [-f address_family | -p protocol]
netstat -m [-m]
netstat -r [-Aaln] [-f address_family]
netstat -rs [-s]
```

Looks like it needs one parameter for `-p` to specify the types of protocol,but I don't want and don't know the type,then how to solve my question,thanks!

**It's a problem on Mac and easy to check,so I wish all the answers can test your solution on your mac machine at first.And maybe the answer is not single,So I'm waiting for your different but useful answers.Thanks for all who pay attention to this question.**

Comment: I don't have a mac to test on but I'm fairly sure the `fuser` command can do this.

Comment: @Score_Under,I think I can't make it by `fuser` command,`fuser` displays the PIDs of processes using the specified files or file systems,it can be used to find process which satisfying some conditions,but I want to get port used by one process which I have known its name and pid.

Answer (score 11):

On OS X you can get the PID of the process holding a port using the `-v` switch.  The `-v` switch actually turns on verbose output which includes the PID.

If you are using `netstat -anp` on Linux then I believe you should be able to get a similar result on OS X using `netstat -anv`.

If you are only interested in inet ports then you can use:

```
netstat -anvf inet
```

Or TCP sockets:

```
netstat -anvp tcp
```

Or UDP sockets:

```
netstat -anvp udp
```

To only return TCP entries for a specific PID, for example `PID == 86` you can pipe the output of `netstat` through `awk`:

```
netstat -anvp tcp | awk '{ if ($9 == 86) print }'
```

In the verbose output from `netstat` the PID is in the ninth column, hence the test of `$9 == 86`.

Answer (score 4):

For example, if you would like to find memcached as a background process on mac. It is far more better to use below code instead of netstat.

```
sudo lsof -i -P|grep memcached
```

Answer (score 2):

As mttrb said: (but easy to filter with grep)

For tcp:

```
netstat -anvp tcp | grep <pid>
```

For udp:

```
netstat -anvp udp | grep <pid>
```

Tested in my El Capitan, working ok.

Comment: Simply grepping for the PID is likely to retrieve incorrect answers.  For example if I am grepping for PID 86 then I will also get results for PID 386 etc. The grep will also find results where the search term appears somewhere other than the PID column of the output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lsof`, like `lsof -p <pid> | egrep 'TCP \*|UDP \*'`, tweak the egrep pattern to meet your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

**BSD netstat** is a bit different from **Linux netstat**, and OSX uses BSD netstat.

Instead of the `-p` switch, (limits display to a single protocol), use `-f inet`, (limits display to a single protocol family, e.g. `inet`, `inet6` etc.).  Or use `-4` which is short for `-f inet`.

> ```
>  -4      Is shorthand for -f inet
>
>  -6      Is shorthand for -f inet6
>
>  -f   address_family, -p protocol
>  Limit display to those records of the specified address_family or a
>  single protocol.  The following address families and protocols are
>  recognized:
>
>  Family              Protocols
>  inet (AF_INET)          divert, icmp, igmp, ip, ipsec, pim,
>                  sctp, tcp, udp
>  inet6 (AF_INET6)        icmp6, ip6, ipsec6, rip6, tcp, udp
>  pfkey (PF_KEY)          pfkey
>  atalk (AF_APPLETALK)        ddp
>  netgraph, ng (AF_NETGRAPH)  ctrl, data
>  ipx (AF_IPX)            ipx, spx
>  unix (AF_UNIX)
>  link (AF_LINK)
> ```

-from BSD ['man netstat'](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netstat&sektion=1).

Comment: but i can't make it still,i typed `netstat -anf inet  | grep <pid>`,but nothing output,and when use -4 as an option.the command failed,showing that it's a illegal option.Can you show me a demo on your machine?thanks very much.

Comment: Can  '-f' be globbed?  What happens when you do `netstat -an -f inet` with no *grep*?  (Note: I've no OSX system here, just linux.)

Comment: it doesn't show pid or process name in its result,so I can't use `grep` to filter it.